# Dark mode for all activites

Tags: java, android

I created the dark mode and it's works perfectly fine with setting activity where is I have my switch, but i can't added to another activity (i don't know how).
here is my code

```
sharedprefs = new SharedPrefs(this);
    if (sharedprefs.loadNightModeState()==true){
        setTheme(R.style.darktheme);
    }
    else setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

if (sharedprefs.loadNightModeState()==true){
        darkmode.setChecked(true);
    }
    darkmode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                sharedprefs.setNightModeState(true);
                restartApp();
            }
            else {
                sharedprefs.setNightModeState(false);
                restartApp();
            }
        }

        public void restartApp() {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

And i have another code in SharedPrefs.java

```
      public class SharedPrefs {
    SharedPreferences mySharedPref ;
    public SharedPrefs(Context context) {
        mySharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("filename",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    // this method will save the nightMode State : True or False
    public void setNightModeState(Boolean state) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("NightMode",state);
        editor.commit();
    }
    // this method will load the Night Mode State
    public Boolean loadNightModeState (){
        Boolean state = mySharedPref.getBoolean("NightMode",false);
        return  state;
    }
}
```

How i can make it work for every Activity?

Comment: Try using the `setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);` before inflating the layout inside onCreate method

Comment: Do you call `setTheme` as well in other activities except settings?

Comment: Don't know how to call

Answer (score 0):

Try put this in the beginning of each activity, when the onCreate method start. It is what I have used and it works perfectly for me.

```
        SharedPreferences userPref = androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    //Use preference to set night or light mode
    if(userPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.displayMode),false)){
        if(userPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.overideMode), true)){
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }
    }else{
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
    }
```

PS - just make sure to change the variables that I am using to what you use otherwise obviously it won't work. Let me know if you get stuck. All the best!!